# Make a LISTVIEW in android studio but can't run the app ("KEEPS STOPPING")?

Tags: android-studio

I make a listview in android studio. My expession is: [List your menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ziF.png)
And this is my code at Menu.java class

```
package com.example.listviewassigment;

public class Menu {
    String name,nodishes,sale;
    int image;

    public Menu(String name, String nodishes, String sale, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nodishes = nodishes;
        this.sale = sale;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

And this is MenuAdapter.java. I think problem in here, cause i can't find getView method on android.widget.ArrayAdapter, and i just code it without suggestion:

```
package com.example.listviewassigment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menu> {
    private int position;
    @Nullable
    private View view;
    private ViewGroup parent;

    public MenuAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Menu> dataArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_dish, dataArrayList);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View View, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Menu listmenu = getItem(position);

        if(view==null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_dish,parent,false);
        }

        ImageView imagedish = view.findViewById(R.id.imagedish);
        TextView titledish = view.findViewById(R.id.titledish);
        TextView nodishes = view.findViewById(R.id.nodishes);
        TextView nodiscounteddishes = view.findViewById(R.id.nodiscounteddishes);

        imagedish.setImageResource(listmenu.image);
        titledish.setText(listmenu.name);
        nodishes.setText(listmenu.nodishes);
        nodiscounteddishes.setText(listmenu.sale);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.listviewassigment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.listviewassigment.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    MenuAdapter menuAdapter;
    ArrayList<Menu> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Menu menu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        int[] imagedish = {R.drawable.pizza,R.drawable.desert,R.drawable.beverage};
        String[] titledish = {"Pizza","Desert","Beverage"};
        String[] nodishes = {"5 sản phẩm","3 sản phẩm","6 sản phẩm"};
        String[] nodiscounteddishes = {"5 đang giảm giá","3 đang giảm giá","6 đang giảm giá"};

        for (int i=0;i< imagedish.length;i++) {
            menu = new Menu(titledish[i],nodishes[i],nodiscounteddishes[i],imagedish[i]);
            dataArrayList.add(menu);
        }
        menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(MainActivity.this,dataArrayList);
        binding.lsMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
        binding.lsMenu.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

I don't know what wrong with the app. It keeps stopping when i run it. Please, i need to solve this problem as soon as possible, so please help me. Sorry because my bad english to explain my prob.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in the MainActivity and MenuAdapter.

1. MainActivity

Replace this code

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

on

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

2. Fixed MenuAdapter

   ```
   public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menu> {
   public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Menu> dataArrayList) {
       super(context, R.layout.item_dish, dataArrayList);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = convertView;

       if (view == null) {
           view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_dish, parent, false);
       }

       Menu listmenu = getItem(position);

       ImageView imagedish = view.findViewById(R.id.imagedish);
       TextView titledish = view.findViewById(R.id.titledish);
       TextView nodishes = view.findViewById(R.id.nodishes);
       TextView nodiscounteddishes = view.findViewById(R.id.nodiscounteddishes);

       if (listmenu != null) {
           imagedish.setImageResource(listmenu.image);
           titledish.setText(listmenu.name);
           nodishes.setText(listmenu.nodishes);
           nodiscounteddishes.setText(listmenu.sale);
       }

       return view;
   }
   ```

This code can also be optimized, but you can do this after you check its performance.